# comparing two different data types with compareTo method

Tags: java, compareto

I have a a class WordCount that implements Set, but I'm having trouble using the comareTo method in WordCount class who get the method from the Word class. I'm trying to compare Word object to String object, but in the end Word is a String also, so why is it giving me errors?

Word class

```
public class Word implements Comparable<String>{

    String word;
    int count;

    public Word(String s)
    {
        word = s;
        count = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(String o) {
        return word.compareTo(o);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return word + "(" + count + ")";
    }   

}
```

I'm having error in this class when using the compareTo method

```
public class WordCount implements Set<Word>{

    private Word[] items;
    private int size;

    public WordCount()
    {
       items = new Word[5]; 
       size = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Word s)
    {
        int i = 0;

        //grow array as needed      
        if (size >= items.length) {
            items = grow(items);
        }


        while (i < size) { 

            if (items[i].compareTo(s) > 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (items[i].equals(s)) {
                return;
            }
            i++;
        }

        items[i] = s;
        size++;


    }

    @Override
    public void show()
    {
        for(Word s : items)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public Word[] grow(Word[] a) {
        Word[] newA = new Word[a.length + 5];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, newA, 0, a.length);
        return newA;
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI, it is _really_ bad code practice to have a class `Foo` that implements `Comparable<Bar>` when `Bar` is not at _least_ a supertype of `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Declare your Word class as `Comparable<Word>.`  (As @Louis Wasserman commented, almost always, a class is Comparable to itself or a superclass)

then

```
 @Override
    public int compareTo(Word o) {
        return word.compareTo(o.word);
    }
```

Also, consider getting rid of Word altogether, and instead use a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is the word you are counting, and the value is the count.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but this is homework and classes can't be change, I just have to implement them...

Answer (score 2):

The `compareTo` method in your Word class is expecting a string parameter, but you're passing it a `Word` instance when you call it in your WordCount class. Your `Word` class doesn't extend the `String` class, so you have a mismatched type error.

Comment: Nor can it extend String. 1+.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the code... I can't believe that no one sees why the comparison is not working... is missing something...

Comment: Actually yes, there is something wrong with the code, and I've already told you what it is. You're passing a `Word` object to a method that's expecting a `String` parameter. How is it that you do not see that?

Comment: @miatech: `"There's nothing wrong with the code"`? Have you read anything that's been posted? You've already been told why your code isn't working. I recommend that you just compare Word for Word, and change any Strings that you want to compare into a Word object for comparison.

Comment: You could solve it with `items[i].compareTo(s.getWord()) > 0`, but again this is bad form. Better to use `Comparable<Word>`.

Comment: @miatech It's a poor practice to follow, but yes that would work (assuming that your `word` member is public).

Comment: one of the tag says: homework, so sometimes we have to work with what was given to us, and in this case the class skeleton and attributes was given; therefore can't be modified

Comment: @miatech It would have been good of you to post that as part of your original question.